# How do I write a classes that don't introduce breaking changes into my program when they are modified?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm pretty new to programing and have written some small simple applications in angular, but I have taken on a much larger project than I am used to, 5 services and over 40 components that pass data and depend on each other but I find that when I make a change to one of the classes it introduces breaking changes all over the program. I've tried to use interfaces to defined the inputs and outputs of the classes and services however anytime I need to add a property to one of the interfaces it introduces typescript compilation errors everywhere that interface is being used... there has to be a better way any one have any insights?

**Simple example below:**

interface

```
export interface testInterface {
  prop1:string
}
```

service 1

```
export sampleService {
  run(test: string): testInterface{
    var Output: testInterface
    // logic
    return Output
  }
}
```

class 1

```
export class sampleClass {
  constructor(private ds: sampleService){}
  this.ds.run()
}
```

all three of these break if you introduce changes to any of these; is there a better way?

Comment: Can you make your example code into a [mcve] as described by [ask]?  Right now that code has typos in it and doesn't quite demonstrate your claim that "all three of these break if you introduce changes to any of these".  And I don't think I understand the use case; don't you want code to break if it's no longer correct?  Maybe you just want the new properties to be optional?  Not sure.  Good luck!

Comment: If 100 classes utilize an interface, then 100 classes must agree to abide by the contract established by that interface. If you change the interface, you change the contract. You _must_ change 100 classes so they comply with the NEW contract. The answer, is to understand the data model of your application so you can minimize the changes to the contracts you establish with the interfaces. As to your code ::: it adds nothing to the conversation.

Comment: Isn't it the purpose of the interfaces and classes?